# Disabling certain inputs in table on button press

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I currently have a table that contains a few values, 2 input fields and a button for each row in that table. What I want to happen is that when I press the button in the third row, the input fields in the third row become disabled. The other rows should remain unaffected. Unfortunately, due to the nature of the program, adding ID's to the inputs and buttons is not possible.

Does anyone know of a good way to go about this?

```
<tr>
    <td>Text A</td>
    <td>Text B</td>
    <td><input class="editable"></td>
    <td>Text C</td>
    <td><input class="editable></td>
    <td>Text D</td>
    <td><button class="disableInput">OK</button></td>
<tr>
```

I have ~40 rows like this

Also, due to the table constantly autosaving to a database (for the input) the table gets refreshed every ~0.5 seconds

Comment: and where is your code so far?

Comment: please explain the 'nature of the program'

Comment: Each row has input fields and buttons you mean?

Comment: @Sionnach733 The table is generated by an external resource over which I have no control, I just pipe in the data and get the HTML for a table back. This does unfortunately mean I cannot simply give all of the fields and buttons ID's without having to write an immense load of JS (I think). I also cannot just drop this external resource as the person I am writing this website for has demanded that I use it for the table.

Comment: @SandeepNayak Indeed

Comment: Are you using  `jQuery`?

Comment: @SandeepNayak Yes, I am

Comment: @FullyHumanProgrammer  http://jsfiddle.net/sandenay/ddo0Ln9L/

Comment: None of the solutions I got so far have been working (unfortunately)... I know this is probably because of a lack of info from my side, so I apologize for that. I shall edit my question to have an example of how a row currently looks (code-wise). Hoping that will help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(tableId).on("click", "button", function(){
    $(this).closest("tr").find("input").attr("disabled", true);
})
```

Comment: How can you assume the OP is using jQuery?

Comment: Because who doesn't these days Sandeep. Unless you are not interested in saving time

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via traversing the DOM.

```js
$('.disableInput').on('click',function(){                      
     var input = $(this).closest('tr').find('input');
     var currstatus = input.prop('disabled');
     input.prop('disabled',!currstatus);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
     <td><input type="text" name="somthing[]"></td>
     <td><input type="text" name="something[]"></td>
     <td><button class="disableInput">Toggle Input</button></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
     <td><input type="text" name="somthing[]"></td>
     <td><input type="text" name="something[]"></td>
     <td><button class="disableInput">Toggle Input</button></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
     <td><input type="text" name="somthing[]"></td>
     <td><input type="text" name="something[]"></td>
     <td><button class="disableInput">Toggle Input</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery, you can do something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("table td .btn").click(function() {
    if ($(this).closest("tr").find("input").attr("disabled") === "disabled"){
      $(this).closest("tr").find("input").removeAttr("disabled", "disabled");
      $(this).closest("tr").find("button").text("Disbale");
    }  
    else{
      
      $(this).closest("tr").find("input").attr("disabled", "disabled");
      $(this).closest("tr").find("button").text("Enable");
     } 
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn" type="button" />Disable</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn" type="button" />Disable</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn" type="button" />Disable</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```